# Error when migrating from Babel 5 to 6 (ReferenceError: exports is not defined)

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using Gulp and Babel to compile client-side es6 code to es5. After upgrade I got this error (in the browser):
`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

The reason for this error, is that Babel compiles my client scripts as CommonJS modules and adds this lines in the beginning of each file:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { // <-- ReferenceError: exports is not defined
  value: true
});
```

But I'm not using any UMD/CommonJS module loaders on the client, so this code causes errors. With Babel 5, to avoid this, I was using option `modules: 'ignore'` in my gulpfile:

```
return gulp.src(src, {base: 'src'})
   .pipe(babel({
        modules: 'ignore' // <-- dropped from Babel 6
   }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

so it compiled my scripts as is, raw and clear. But this option was dropped from Babel 6 and now it causes error
`[ReferenceError: [BABEL] ..myscript.js: Unknown option: base.modules]`
, so I had to comment this line.

Is there any alternative to `modules: 'ignore'` in Babel 6?

Comment: So it looks to me if you specify in the plugins parts you can get the compiler to transform you ES6/7 code to use modules... [source](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-umd/). Do you use imports or anything like that?

Comment: @CallumLinington, Thanks for response. I'm using imports/exports only on server side, but the client is separated and connects to server via API. I'm not using Webpack or Browserify, just using Babel to transform es6 code to es5.I tried to install a module you suggested, so it's now wraps every my file with UMD code. But my code is more oriented to use global scope (`window` object), and i'd prefer to stick to the way it's already done.

Comment: Do you have Babel configuration somewhere to enable presets? I assume you've enabled `es2015`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth, Yes, my .babelrc looks like `{"presets": ["es2015"], "plugins": ["syntax-async-functions", "transform-regenerator"]}` (two plugins for async/await functionality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `es2015` [this set of plugins](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-es2015/index.js) enabled by default. Note that `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` is in there.

If you wish to not perform any type of module conversion, you'll need to explicitly list the plugins that you'd like to use, rather than using `es2015`.

Comment: How could I not to figure it out my self... So simple... Thank you!

Comment: Updated link to the [set of plugins](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-es2015/package.json)